# css text overlapped with the checkboxes

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my CSS styling. For some reasons the `Text1`, `Text2`, `Text3` and `Text4` are overlapping with the content and not appear. Could u help me please? I need them to be to the right of the checkboxes.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jp6j.png]

Here is my code

HTML

```
<div ID="campaignDiv" runat="server" >
    <ul>
        <li>
            Text1
            <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="1"/>
            <label for="1"></label>
        </li>
         <li>
             Text2
            <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="2"/>
            <label for="2"></label>
        </li>
         <li>
             Text3
            <input type="checkbox" id="3" value="3"/>
            <label for="3"></label>
        </li>
         <li>
             Text4
            <input type="checkbox" id="4" value="4"/>
            <label for="4"></label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#DropdownSeviceLink {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

a#DropdownServiceLink:visited {
    color: inherit;
}

#campaignDiv {
    background-color: #374954;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position:relative;
    top: 40px;
    right: 0;
}

    #campaignDiv ul {
        color: #fff;
        list-style: none;
        overflow: auto;
        padding-left:5px;

    }

    #campaignDiv input[type=checkbox] {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

        #campaignDiv input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
            left: 60px;
            background: #26ca28;
        }

    #campaignDiv li {
        width: 100px;/*120*/
        height: 25px;/*40*/
        background: #333;
        margin: 13px 0px;/*20px 60px*/
        border-radius: 50px;
        position: relative;
    }

        #campaignDiv li:before {
            content: 'On';
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;/*12*/
            left: 13px;
            height: 2px;
            color: #26ca28;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        #campaignDiv li:after {
            content: 'Off';
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;/*12*/
            left: 71px;/*84*/
            height: 2px;
            color: #111;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        #campaignDiv li label {
            display: block;
            width: 36px;/*52*/
            height: 18px;/*22*/
            border-radius: 50px;
            -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
            -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
            -o-transition: all .5s ease;
            -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
            transition: all .5s ease;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            top: 4px;/*9*/
            z-index: 1;
            left: 12px;
            background: #ddd;
        }
```

Comment: Include your jsfiddle. You haven't.

Comment: @AthanasiosEmmanouilidis I did now

Comment: I would first suggest that you put the text inside the labels.

Comment: Just for historic purposes, there was a jsfiddle in the question but now its code is pasted inside the question. Marco Dinatsoli asked to delete the fiddle for some unknown reason and I deleted it. I'm really sorry if I shouldn't have done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer.

I added all "Text1" "Text2" etc in a `<span>` tag and then styled them with `margin-left:110px.`

HTML

```
  <div ID="campaignDiv" runat="server" >
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <span class="texts">Text1</span>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="1" value="1"/>
                                    <label for="1"></label>
                                </li>
                                 <li>
                                    <span class="texts">Text2</span>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="2" value="2"/>
                                    <label for="2"></label>
                                </li>
                                 <li>
                                    <span class="texts">Text3</span>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="3" value="3"/>
                                    <label for="3"></label>
                                </li>
                                 <li>
                                    <span class="texts">Text4</span>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="4" value="4"/>
                                    <label for="4"></label>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

CSS

```
.texts
{
    margin-left:110px;
}

#DropdownSeviceLink {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

a#DropdownServiceLink:visited {
    color: inherit;
}

#campaignDiv {
    background-color: #374954;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position:relative;
    top: 40px;
    right: 0;
}

    #campaignDiv ul {
        color: #fff;
        list-style: none;
        overflow: auto;
        padding-left:5px;

    }

    #campaignDiv input[type=checkbox] {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

        #campaignDiv input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
            left: 60px;
            background: #26ca28;
        }

    #campaignDiv li {
        width: 100px;/*120*/
        height: 25px;/*40*/
        background: #333;
        margin: 13px 0px;/*20px 60px*/
        border-radius: 50px;
        position: relative;
    }

        #campaignDiv li:before {
            content: 'On';
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;/*12*/
            left: 13px;
            height: 2px;
            color: #26ca28;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        #campaignDiv li:after {
            content: 'Off';
            position: absolute;
            top: 5px;/*12*/
            left: 71px;/*84*/
            height: 2px;
            color: #111;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        #campaignDiv li label {
            display: block;
            width: 36px;/*52*/
            height: 18px;/*22*/
            border-radius: 50px;
            -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
            -moz-transition: all .5s ease;
            -o-transition: all .5s ease;
            -ms-transition: all .5s ease;
            transition: all .5s ease;
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            top: 4px;/*9*/
            z-index: 1;
            left: 12px;
            background: #ddd;
        }
```

Comment: Kindly tell me what did you change

Comment: I added all "Text1" "Text2" etc in a <span> tag and then styled them with margin-left:110px.

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer.

Comment: @AndyG no need for explanation, I understood it

Comment: @AthanasiosEmmanouilidis +1 I will accept it when the system allows. please remove the jfiddle link, thanks for understanding

Comment: I deleted the jsfiddle link.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I deleted the jsfiddle link, just add your CSS code also here.